# BSOD: "system_license_violation" Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Got this BSOD "system_license_violation" after a reboot. I do have a correct license and I was unable to restore to an older state of the machine.

When I tried to refresh, reset, or restore it It always told that it wasn´t possible and that my drive is locked(?)

Edit1:

This is a permanent loop.

Comment: [Unless you provided us with more information we can't help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559317(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Actually I didnt get any any Parameter Code. Just the bsod with "system_license_violation".

Comment: I suggest you boot to a Windows 10 installation disk then use that to reverse your upgrade.  Unless you provide us more information we cannot help.

Comment: By reverse upgrade you mean go back to Win 8? Win 10 was running stable for almost a month.

Comment: Well without the parameter information, we cannot determine the reason your getting it, which means we can't tell you how to solve it.  Something has happened to cause this BSOD though.

Comment: Is there any way to force the parameter information to show up?